# Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found

Tags: linux, arm, u-boot

I am trying to build the linux kernel image for the Beaglebone black right from scratch!

i am following the tutorials referred by Free-electrons(http://free-electrons.com/training/kernel/)

I am posting the env settings in uboot and the log file of the result.

As you can see kernel is not booting and results into kernel panic. Please give suggestions.

```
U-Boot 2014.04-dirty (Dec 06 2014 - 00:59:13)

I2C:   ready
DRAM:  512 MiB
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
Using default environment

Net:   <ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
cpsw, usb_ether
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
mmc0 is current device
SD/MMC found on device 0
reading uEnv.txt
161 bytes read in 3 ms (51.8 KiB/s)
Loaded environment from uEnv.txt
Importing environment from mmc ...
Running uenvcmd ...
reading uImage
4961872 bytes read in 272 ms (17.4 MiB/s)
reading am335x-boneblack.dtb
26024 bytes read in 7 ms (3.5 MiB/s)
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 81000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-3.12.1
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    4961808 Bytes = 4.7 MiB
   Load Address: 80008000
   Entry Point:  80008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 82000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x82000000
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Using Device Tree in place at 82000000, end 820095a7

Starting kernel ....
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .

    1.748225] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: detected phy mask fffffffe
[    1.762278] libphy: 4a101000.mdio: probed
[    1.766516] davinci_mdio 4a101000.mdio: phy[0]: device 4a101000.mdio:00, driver SMSC LAN8710/LAN8720
[    1.776408] Detected MACID = d0:39:72:3b:bd:35
[    1.787700] omap_rtc 44e3e000.rtc: setting system clock to 2000-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (946684800)
[    1.799704] Freeing unused kernel memory: 396K (c074d000 - c07b0000)
[    1.807800] Failed to execute /init
[    1.812103] Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance.
```

**And here is the printenv output from u-boot:**

```
U-Boot# printenv
arch=arm
baudrate=115200
board=am335x
board_name=A335BNLT
board_rev=00C0
boot_fdt=try
bootcmd=setenv mmcdev 0; setenv bootpart 0; run mmcboot;
bootcount=1
bootdelay=1
bootdir=/boot
bootenv=uEnv.txt
bootfile=zImage
bootpart=0:2
console=ttyO0,115200n8
cpu=armv7
dfu_alt_info_emmc=rawemmc mmc 0 3751936
dfu_alt_info_mmc=boot part 0 1;rootfs part 0 2;MLO fat 0 1;MLO.raw mmc 100 100;u-boot.img.raw mmc 300 400;spl-os-args.raw mmc 80 80;spl-os-image.raw mmc 900 2000;spl-os-args fat 0 1;spl-os-image fat 0 1;u-boot.img fat 0 1;uEnv.txt fat 0 1
dfu_alt_info_ram=kernel ram 0x80200000 0xD80000;fdt ram 0x80F80000 0x80000;ramdisk ram 0x81000000 0x4000000
eth1addr=d0:39:72:3b:bd:37
ethact=cpsw
ethaddr=d0:39:72:3b:bd:35
fdt_high=0xffffffff
fdtaddr=0x80F80000
fdtfile=undefined
findfdt=if test $board_name = A335BONE; then setenv fdtfile am335x-bone.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = A335BNLT; then setenv fdtfile am335x-boneblack.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = A33515BB; then setenv fdtfile am335x-evm.dtb; fi; if test $board_name = A335X_SK; then setenv fdtfile am335x-evmsk.dtb; fi; if test $fdtfile = undefined; then echo WARNING: Could not determine device tree to use; fi;
importbootenv=echo Importing environment from mmc ...; env import -t $loadaddr $filesize
loadaddr=0x80200000
loadbootenv=load mmc ${mmcdev} ${loadaddr} ${bootenv}
loadfdt=load mmc ${bootpart} ${fdtaddr} ${bootdir}/${fdtfile}
loadimage=load mmc ${bootpart} ${loadaddr} ${bootdir}/${bootfile}
loadramdisk=load mmc ${mmcdev} ${rdaddr} ramdisk.gz
mmcargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${mmcroot} rootfstype=${mmcrootfstype}
mmcboot=mmc dev ${mmcdev}; if mmc rescan; then echo SD/MMC found on device ${mmcdev};if run loadbootenv; then echo Loaded environment from ${bootenv};run importbootenv;fi;if test -n $uenvcmd; then echo Running uenvcmd ...;run uenvcmd;fi;if run loadimage; then run mmcloados;fi;fi;
mmcdev=0
mmcloados=run mmcargs; if test ${boot_fdt} = yes || test ${boot_fdt} = try; then if run loadfdt; then bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}; else if test ${boot_fdt} = try; then bootz; else echo WARN: Cannot load the DT; fi; fi; else bootz; fi;
mmcroot=/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro
mmcrootfstype=ext4 rootwait
netargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=${serverip}:${rootpath},${nfsopts} rw ip=dhcp
netboot=echo Booting from network ...; setenv autoload no; dhcp; tftp ${loadaddr} ${bootfile}; tftp ${fdtaddr} ${fdtfile}; run netargs; bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdtaddr}
nfsopts=nolock
partitions=uuid_disk=${uuid_gpt_disk};name=rootfs,start=2MiB,size=-,uuid=${uuid_gpt_rootfs}
ramargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${ramroot} rootfstype=${ramrootfstype}
ramboot=echo Booting from ramdisk ...; run ramargs; bootz ${loadaddr} ${rdaddr} ${fdtaddr}
ramroot=/dev/ram0 rw ramdisk_size=65536 initrd=${rdaddr},64M
ramrootfstype=ext2
rdaddr=0x81000000
rootpath=/export/rootfs
soc=am33xx
spiargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} ${optargs} root=${spiroot} rootfstype=${spirootfstype}
spiboot=echo Booting from spi ...; run spiargs; sf probe ${spibusno}:0; sf read ${loadaddr} ${spisrcaddr} ${spiimgsize}; bootz ${loadaddr}
spibusno=0
spiimgsize=0x362000
spiroot=/dev/mtdblock4 rw
spirootfstype=jffs2
spisrcaddr=0xe0000
static_ip=${ipaddr}:${serverip}:${gatewayip}:${netmask}:${hostname}::off
stderr=serial
stdin=serial
stdout=serial
usbnet_devaddr=d0:39:72:3b:bd:37
vendor=ti
ver=U-Boot 2014.04-dirty (Dec 06 2014 - 00:59:13)
```

Comment: Try passing init?

Comment: @DisplayName, Yes i have passed initramfs to the kernel during configuration before building.